# What are the corner coordinates of a global map in meters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84

We all know that the corner coordinates of a global map in degrees are -180, 90; -180, -90; 180, 90; and 180, -90 (top left; bottom left; top right; bottom right).

So what are the corresponding coordinates in meters in arcgis using D_WGS_1984 datum?

I need to know these coordinates to define projection for my MODIS blue marble image.

Answer (score -2):

WGS84 Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000
Projected Bounds: -20037508.3428, -10018754.1714, 20037508.3428, 10018754.1714

Found from here http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-plate-carree/

Comment: This only works for a sphere with R=6378137 meters. WGS84 uses an ellipsoid, as do many other projections of the world.